# Getting java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

Tags: java, android

I am new to android.
I am getting an error while updating through HttpClient like  java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

```
public static String newupdateProf(String memid, String gender,
                String pdata, String dob, String pimg) throws IOException,
                JSONException {
            // System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
            final HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            final HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(websrv.trim() + "/newUpdtProf");

            JSONStringer img = new JSONStringer().object().key("prof").object()
                    .key("memid").value(memid.trim()).key("gender")
                    .value(gender.trim()).key("pdata").value(pdata.trim())
                    .key("dob").value(dob.trim()).key("pimg").value(pimg.trim())
                    .endObject().endObject();
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(img.toString());
            httpost.setEntity(se);
            httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpost);

            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            InputStream stream = httpEntity.getContent();
            String result = convertStreamToString(stream);
            return result.trim();

        }
```

Please help me. 
I also tried

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
```

but it's not working.

Comment: the answer was that it's the server's fault - it had to close the connection after each request .

it might be that android keeps a pool of connections and use the old one or something like that

Answer (score 8):

Set the http.keepAlive system property to false before issuing any HTTP requests.

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
```

Comment: It worked for me. But what is the explanation of his answer ?

Comment: Worked for me! Is there any chance that this solution backfires in some case?